# List deployed webapps in Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I need to get a list of deployed webapps in Apache Tomcat. Also, for each webapp I need to get a list of initialized servlets and JSPs. Any ideas how this can be done?

I've found that the directory `\tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\` contains a child directory for each webapp. Could there be any other deployed webapps that aren't present there?

Answer (score 26):

In order to get a list of deployed apps of your tomcat you just need configure user/roles and use **/manager/text/list** tomcat endpoint

## Configure user and roles in Tomcat

Add this in your **/.../.../TOMCAT_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml**

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-script"/>

<user username="my_user" password="my_pass" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,admin-gui,admin-script"/>
```

You could skip "admin-gui" & "admin-script" roles if you will not perform admin operations.

After that, restart tomcat

## List apps using browser

Go to your favorite browser and enter this url:

```
http://some_ip:some_port/manager/text/list
```

A login will appear. Enter the user/password configured in your **TOMCAT_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml**

## Using command line

Just execute this:

```
curl -v -u my_user:my_pass http://127.0.0.1:some_port/manager/text/list
```

The result should be:

```
OK - Listed applications for virtual host localhost
/manager:running:0:manager
/:running:0:ROOT
/docs:running:0:docs
/examples:running:0:examples
/host-manager:running:0:host-manager
/my_app:running:0:my_app
/my_other_app:running:0:my_other_app
....
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

List apps with curl is used by a plugins related to automated tomcat deploys (Devops)

HTH

Comment: I had to use localhost, not 127.0.0.1, but it worked - thanks :)

Comment: This worked perfectly - note it works for me without roles "admin-gui" & "admin-script"

Answer (score 11):

You can do it by using javax.management. It will look like

```
private Iterable<String> collectAllDeployedApps() {
    try {
        final Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
        final Set<ObjectName> instances = findServer()
                .queryNames(new ObjectName("Tomcat:j2eeType=WebModule,*"), null);
        for (ObjectName each : instances) {
            result.add(substringAfterLast(each.getKeyProperty("name"), "/")); //it will be in format like //localhost/appname 
        }
        return result;
    } catch (MalformedObjectNameException e) {
         //handle
    }
}

private MBeanServer findServer() {
    ArrayList<MBeanServer> servers = MBeanServerFactory.findMBeanServer(null);
    for (MBeanServer eachServer : servers) {
        for (String domain : eachServer.getDomains()) {
            if (domain.equals("Tomcat")) {
                return eachServer;
            }
        }
    }
    //handle. We are not in Tomcat.
}
```

Comment: In Tomcat 7+, you might need to change "Tomcat" to "Catalina" in order for the sample code to work. Once making that change, the sample code worked perfectly.

Comment: @WilliamBrendel - I have a similar issue, but in my case I cannot login (I'm instrumenting the application) - and therefore the list of apps is always empty. Any idea? My question in detail can be found here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39488852/tomcat-7-get-the-application-name-during-runtime-without-login-via-java-agent

Answer (score 5):

[Manual quote: List_Currently_Deployed_Applications](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#List_Currently_Deployed_Applications)

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/text/list
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to do it. But there is a manager application in the standard distribution of tomcat, which lists the deployed apps. Sourcecode is provided, so you could have a look there.

Regarding your question about other webapps: Yes, there could be other webapps, which resides not in the webapp directory. They could be specified in the server.xml.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I found for information about the deployed applications and their content (including servlets, files, connections and such) is to install [Lambda Probe](http://www.lambdaprobe.org/d/index.htm) in addition to whatever the tomcat instance is serving.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [Apache Tomcat manual](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/). Section 5 is about the Manager application in Tomcat, which does just that.

Comment: i did have a look there, but /manager/list probably belongs to previous version. anyways, i need to get the list form inside a filter

Answer (score -2):

http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/wiki/Features seems like a good place to look.