# List deployed Webserices in Tomee

Tags: rest, web-services, jersey, apache-tomee

I have an application deployed on Tomee which is hosting lots of web services which are written using Jersey framework.

How to identify how many web-services(URLs) are hosted by the application and what is the class having the source code?

I have gone through below article but it gives the list of hosted applications instead of giving list of web-services under one application.
[List deployed webapps in Apache Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805843/list-deployed-webapps-in-apache-tomcat)

Comment: Note sure if you are searching for a specific view on this but the "CxfRsHttpListener" actually lists all deployed application endpoints with path and method on startup (server.log).

Answer (score 0):

If you want an easy way to list these out visually, start up the application locally. Next launch `jconsole` and connect to the TomEE JVM.

You can then browse the CXF JMX Beans in the tree and you'll be able to find all the deployed endpoints.

I think Kekzpanda's comment is a great method to do this as well: in the startup log TomEE will list all of the deployed endpoints the Path to each.